# Displaying Adult Site on a Resume

Tags: resume

Let's say that I was the owner of an adult site of an explicit nature. This site I also self-developed and later sold for a somewhat significant sum of money. Also taking into account that I'm a relatively young developer without much in the way of professional/commercial experience who is now applying for work. Would it be detrimental to mention my work on this site on a resume? Should I try to underplay the fact I was the owner at one point? Or would most hiring people look past to see the technical merits of the work?

Personally I'm thinking that in the year 21st Century it probably wouldn't be seen as being very different from other any other projects/work, but I figured I'd get a professional opinion.

Comment: Very related question - [here](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/11492/what-are-the-career-risks-of-taking-a-job-related-to-adult-entertainment)

Comment: I imagine it would depend entirely on where you are applying and who's doing the hiring.

Comment: @enderland it's a very close duplicate I think

Comment: Anyway, this will really depend on where you are trying to work: If you apply building a website for the Catholic Church, mentioning this is not such a brilliant idea, while at Google they probably high-five you.

Comment: @Hilmar I somehow doubt that Google would high five you and go SWEET PRON SITE BRO!! but I may be wrong

Answer (score 3):

The difference between this and the other outstanding questions is that in this case, you appear to be the instigator, not merely a member of a team.

The fact that you 'worked on one' is largely immaterial, if you were simply working on processing payments you are hardly involved with the content.  In general, what's the difference from a software perspective from art, travel snapshots, and erotica? Not much.

Creating such a site raises some interesting questions.  Certainly there is no shortage of initiative.  Such things take work, and it is a hypercompetitive environment, so you must have learned something about marketing.  If all this is recent, then you would have gotten familiar with SEO and the weirdnesses of the search engines.  Seems like if someone wanted you to create and publish a site with politically provocative content, you could hardly demur on the basis of not wanting to get in people's face.  On the other hand, don't expect to find work in school districts or universities.  They will check, and they won't hire you.